# UIPopover for iphone 4.0

Tags: iphone

i would like to know whether iphone 4.0 supports UIPopover?I have tried using but i got this msg in console:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'
```

Answer (score 8):

You should really read the documentation carefully before posting.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

> "Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices"

Comment: So Apple developed its own widget for iBook on iPhone for example ?

Comment: it would appear that way, yes.

Answer (score 2):

For now, UIPopover is for iPads only.